# Calculating probability of unique marbles of a variable set

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you have n unique marbles in a bag. You take n marbles out of the bag with replacement. With infinite trials, on average what fraction of unique marbles will be taken out?

Comment: How do take the average over infinitely many trials?  It's not at all clear what you are asking.  Also, have you done anything at all on this problem yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- What is the probability a particular marble *is* taken out on a particular attempt?
- What is the probability a particular marble *is not* taken out on a particular attempt?
- What is the probability a particular marble *is not* taken out in any of $n$ attempts?
- What is the probability a particular marble *is* taken out in at least one of $n$ attempts?
- What is the expected number of the $n$ marbles taken out in at least one of the $n$ attempts?